# Is this an Adjective Clause?

Tags: dependent-clause

I have a question. Yesterday, in PBS news, I heard

- "a somewhat surreal, pandemic version of **what is usually a full-throated rally to show off a new vice presidential pick**".

How do we understand the structure of this expression?

Is the part that is after "version of" an adjective clause?

Comment: Maybe a noun clause (serving as the object of the preposition "of"), but certainly not an adjective clause since it doesn't seem to modify anything.

Comment: A simpler example is ' ... an overview of _what is available_'.

Comment: No, it's not a clause at all, but a noun phrase in a fused relative construction, functioning as complement of "of".  It's the equivalent of (the more formal) "that which is usually a full-throated rally to show off a new vice presidential pick".

Comment: What is the quickest way to spot fused relative constructions? I had in mind this thing and that's why I added "maybe" to my answer, intuiting it could be a phrase instead @BillJ

Comment: One obvious clue is that there is no 'external' antecedent. This is because the fusion involves the antecedent and the relative word, i.e. they are fused together instead of being expressed separately.  Compare the fused "Whoever said that was lying" with the non-fused "The person who said that was lying", where the single word "whoever" is the equivalent of "the person who".

Comment: Got it. Thanks, BillJ! :)

Comment: Thanks guys, all of these are very helpful!